# Does dispatching to a queue that's owned by an object retain that object?

Tags: objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, retain, reference-counting

Suppose I have a simple call `dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{ /* Empty */ })`, where `self.queue` is a  queue created previously.

Does `self` get retained by the Block in this case, given that there is no `self` reference *inside* the block, but only as a parameter for `dispatch_async()`?

Comment: What does "does self get retained for block" mean? Do you mean, "does self get retained because I'm passing it's queue to dispatch_async?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `self` will not get retained if the block has neither (a) any explicit references to `self`; nor (b) any implicit references to `self` that are generated by referencing any instance variables of `self`. The presence of `self.queue` in the invocation of `dispatch_async` will not cause it to be retained. It's what inside the block that matters.

This is quite easy to demonstrate. Imagine a view controller whose implementation looks like:

```
@interface SecondViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t queue;
@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.stackoverflow.17306228", 0);

    void (^block)(void) = ^(void){
        sleep(10);

        NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    };

    dispatch_async(self.queue, block);
}

@end
```

If you push to this view controller's scene, and then immediately press the "back" button to pop it off, you'll see the view controller immediately be deallocated, and the block will continue to execute. But if you add a class instance variable or property to the `block`, you'll see the view controller retained until after the block completes.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so apple docs states that

> The queue is retained by the system until the block has run to
>   completion.

So the queue will be retained by the system until the block completes the execution, but the `self` won't be retained in this case.

Thanks to @Wain for pointing out my mistake in the previous version of this answer.

Comment: How does retaining the queue result in a retain of `self`?

Comment: I probably used the wrong words in this context, `self` can't be released/dealocated until the queue is released. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sure it can. The queue can continue to exist without `self`. The system is the thing that maintains 'the' persistent reference to the queue.

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe what I just said, @Wain you are perfectly right. I edited my anser.

Comment: hm, ok then. and why other properties used inside the block will result in retaining self? because they "cannot exist without self?"

Comment: Not every time you are using `self.property`  inside a block will result to a retain cycle, have a look over http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html